# How do i avoid logging the output of skipped role in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am skipping a role in Ansible using when condition but it is still printing the task when i run the playbook. Is there a way to not log these task or may be if they are logging then add something like **Task Skipped**?

/roles/copyrepo/tasks/main.yml

```
---
- include: real_tasks.yml
  when: temp.stat.isdir is undefined
```

/roles/copyrepo/tasks/real_tasks.yml

```
    - name: Ensuring that the web deployment folder is created on nodes for each web application
      file:
        path: "{{release_location}}/Release{{release_version}}/{{item}}/webapp"
        state: directory
        mode: 0755
      with_items:
       - "{{ myapps }}"

    - name: Copying the release war files from local server to tomcat nodes
      copy: src={{local_server_release_location}}/{{release_version}}/{{item}}-{{release_version}}.war dest={{release_location}}/Release{{release_version}}/{{item}}
      with_items:
       - "{{ myapps }}"

    - name: Overriding the directory name
      command: mv /temp/myapp-web /temp/myapp
```

`display_skipped_hosts = False` won't work here because the task header will still be shown regardless of whether or not the task is skipped.

How do i avoid showing below headers in my output as they are not being executed?

```
Ensuring that the web deployment folder is created on nodes for each web application...
Tuesday 02 June 2020  16:54:11 +0100 (0:00:00.216)       0:00:07.378 **********
Copying the MyVM release war files from local server to tomcat nodes...
Tuesday 02 June 2020  16:54:11 +0100 (0:00:00.204)       0:00:07.582 **********
Overriding the directory name...
Tuesday 02 June 2020  16:54:12 +0100 (0:00:00.205)       0:00:07.787 **********
```

Let me know if someone can advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unhappy with the [provided selection of stdout callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list), then you can write your own that displays exactly the output you want, formatted exactly how you want. As far as I know, it's even possible to have them [per playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#adding-a-plugin-locally) if you wanted to package the plugin to travel along your normal playbook distribution mechanism